# Elementary velocity problem, two bodies traveling towards eachother

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am lost in the maths of this problem:

> A cyclist starts moving from point A to point B.
>
> At the same time, a second cyclist starts moving from point B to 
>   point A.
>
> Both cyclist meet (pass eachother) at some point (place) in  between 
>   A and B.
>
> The first cyclist,  from the point they meet to  B needs t_1 =   2 h more, in relation to the time it took him moving from A to
>   the  point they meet.
>
> The second cyclist,  from the point they meet to A needs t_2 = 
>    1.2 h less, in relation to the time it took him moving from B to the  point they meet.
>
> Determine the time the first cyclist moved from A to B.
>
> Deterimine the time the second cyclist moved from B to A.
>
> Assume both cyclists moved in a linear motion.

My work so far:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afL3L.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. It's better if you write out your problem and workings out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

$$
d_1 = \mbox{Distance covered by cyclist # 1} \\
d_2 = \mbox{Distance covered by cyclist # 2} \\
D = d_1+d_2\ \  \mbox{Distance between A and B}\\
v_1 = \mbox{Cyclist # 1 speed}\\
v_2 = \mbox{Cyclist # 2 speed}\\
t^* = \mbox{Time to meet}\\
\delta t_1 = 2\\
\delta t_2 = 1.2
$$

we have

$$
v_1 t^* = d_1\\
v_2 t^* = d_2\\
v_1(t^*+\delta t_1) = d_2\\
v_2(t^*-\delta t_2) = d_1\\
d_1+d_2 = D
$$

Now solving for $d_1,d_2,v_1,v_2,t^*$ we get

$$
d_1 = 0.375 D\\
d_2 = 0.625D\\
v_1 = 0.125 D\\
v_2 = 0.20833D\\
t^* = 3
$$

with $v_1 = 0.6 v_2$

Comment: The solution is easy and I have confidence in your capability to solve it.

Comment: Got d2 = 0.625D and then d1 = 0.375D now thinking about how to work v1 and v2

Comment: Now you can get easily the relationship $v_1/v_2$

Comment: i already had found that relationship https://i.stack.imgur.com/afL3L.png

Comment: Now with the third/fourth you can get $t^*$

Comment: If I knew v1 and v2. I haven't found those yet

Comment: Found them v1=0.125D v2=0.20833..D

Comment: Also found t*=3 so firs cyclist 8h second cyclist 4.8h

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and help

Answer (score 0):

Let Cyclist 1 = $C_1$, Cyclist 2 = $C_2$

At time $t=0$mins, $C_1$ is at $A$, $C_2$ is at $B$.

At time $t=T$, $C_1$ is at $M$ and so is $C_2$ (their meeting point)

At time $t=2T-72$, $C_2$ is at $A$.

At time $t=2T+120$, $C_1$ is at $B$.

Note from this that:

$C_1$ took $2T+120$ to do what $C_2$ did in $T$, and $C_1$ did in $T$ what $C_2$ did in $2T-72$.

Therefore:
$$\frac{2T+120}{T}=\frac{T}{2T-72}$$
and solve to find $T$.

Comment: i got time for C1 200 min and time for C2 8 min,  Is there anyway to solve this problem without using quadratic formula?